# How to stop an activity from restarting when back button is pressed?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a `NavigationView` with only two sections. When the drawer is closed, this is how it looks like:

https://ibb.co/VCYKWHL

When I open the drawer, this is how it looks like:

https://ibb.co/pxDnvpL

When I click on the "burger icon" everything comes back to the initial state, which is fine.

The problem is when I press the second section, instead of displaying the "burger icon" the back icon is displayed and once I press it, the activity is finished and started again. This is what I have tried so far:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.fragment_profile, null, navOptions);
            break;

        case R.id.nav_products:
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                    .navigate(R.id.fragment_products, null, navOptions);
            break;
    }
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Where `navOptions` is defined as:

```
navOptions = new NavOptions.Builder()
            .setPopUpTo(R.id.navigation, true)
            .build();
```

I have also overrided `onSupportNavigateUp()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment), drawerLayout);
}
```

How can I have the same "burger icon" no matter on which section I click?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the up button then why do you overriding the function?

Check the Github [link](https://github.com/ImPDP/Grado/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/boredboy/gradpoint/MainActivity.java) to one of the basic app using the navigation drawer. This may solve your problem.